# How can I save a screenshot with each git commit?

Tags: git, screenshot

I'd like to be able to associate an image with some of my [git](/questions/tagged/git) commits, so that I can browse through them at a latter date. I code a lot of visualisations and often find myself wanting to go back to a certain itteration of a graphic that I had done a few days before, in a given project, but struggle to find which actual commit it was by just reading through the comments. If I was able to save a screen grab with my commits, then it would be much easier to pick out the commit I'm interested in.

In [Mike Bostock's talk at the Open Vis Conference](http://youtu.be/fThhbt23SGM?t=22m40s) this year, he talks about an internal tool they created at the New York Times, called Preview, which achieves this functionality; I'm hoping that someone on SO will be able to point me a similar tool which is available to the public.

I've also come across an amusing tool called [lolcommits](http://mroth.github.io/lolcommits/) which uses your webcam to take a selfie on each commit (their website says that git blame has never been so much fun!); so close to what I want, just the wrong image!

Answer (score 2):

Taking and saving the screenshots are easy enough just use the pre-commit/post hooks to generate a screen shot of the image(s) that you are interested in.

The problem is that the git browser doesn't let you view them if they are committed so why not use a simple python script to generate low definition views of the, (potentially only the changed), graphics in your source tree and save them to a directory based on the commit ID possibly generating a web page for that commits - possibly with an automatically generated text for update to that commit.

If your graphics are produced as a result of running the code your pre-commit script could even include a build into a test program which outputs the images.

Comment: are you aware of any such script?

Comment: @Ooker - The python based [pre-commit tool](https://pre-commit.com/) is highly customisable and aware of which files have changed as well as which issue(s)/ticket(s) are mentioned in the commit message. The Pillow library can be used to generate screenshots so I would use that to automate adding a screenshot or images to the first referenced issue _(most issue trackers can add images)_ or to a fixed issue number _possibly in response to a keyword in the commit message_. If the screenshot was done in the `post-commit` hook then the SHA could be included.